# lazy load issue with media boxes jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid, grid

I am using this plugin [here](http://codecanyon.net/item/media-boxes-portfolio-responsive-grid/5683020) but i have some problem to load more images.

You can see there is a button on bottom to load more images but i do not need button to load more i just  want to load more content on scroll.

You can see live example what i am working [here](http://client-acumenadagency.com/acumenadagency/work.html)

My problem is, i just disabled button on bottom to load more because i want to load images on scroll instead click button to show.

```
$('#grid').mediaBoxes({
        filterContainer: '#filter',
        overlayEffect: 'direction-aware',
        boxesToLoadStart: 16, 
        boxesToLoad: 4,
        lazyLoad: true,
        horizontalSpaceBetweenBoxes: 0,
        verticalSpaceBetweenBoxes: 0,
    });
```

Comment: for me its working on scroll (but when i scroll fast, it just adds one layer.)

Comment: Acutely there are more content so you have to go up and than scroll down to see more so i just wana make it smooth. @Cerlin Boss